# FFMPEG set -ss and -to with string

Tags: java, android, ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

I know I can set the start with **-ss** and end with **-to** but can someone please help me to format the following so that I can enter the `-ss` and `-to` with a string?

I want `-ss` to come from

```
String start = editStart.getText().toString();
```

and `-to` to come from

```
String end = editEnd.getText().toString();
```

Here is my ffmpeg string I want to edit, I have entered `-ss` and `-to` to show where I want the above strings to be.

```
String s = "-i" + " " + mVideoUri.toString().replace("file:///", "") + " -filter_complex [1:v][0:v]scale2ref=iw:ih[ovr][base];[ovr]colorchannelmixer=aa=0.7[ovrl];[base][ovrl]overlay[v] -ss -to -map [v]" + directoryToStore + "/" + FileName + mp4;

String[] arguments = s.split(" ");

ExecuteFFMPEG(arguments);
```

Comment: can you please clarify how you are passing values for them. And how do you execute ffmpeg. For example we do Runtime.getRuntime().exec and pass a string with full command line for ffmpeg

Comment: Thank you for looking at this question, please see my edit @OlgaKhylkouskaya

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30197627/ffmpeg-android-execute You don't need to split arguments, just pass a String with -ss and -to. You specified that you can get such values formatter.format(getValueRight).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so you get your start and end point from:

```
String start = editStart.getText().toString();  
String end = editEnd.getText().toString();
```

So instead of splitting the argument do this instead:

```
String[] s = {"-i" ,mVideoUri.toString(),"-filter_complex","[1:v][0:v]scale2ref=iw:ih[ovr][base];[ovr]colorchannelmixer=aa=0.7[ovrl];[base][ovrl]overlay[v]","-ss","start","-to","end","-map","[v]",directoryToStore+"/"+"output.mp4"};
ExecuteFFMPEG(s);
```